# How to extract Spring Data JPA query to separate file

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Spring Data JPA allows to extract `jpql` or `sql` queries to `orm.xml` as described in [Spring Data Jpa Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_xml_named_query_definition).

In such scenario multiple queries would end up in single `orm.xml` file. In our scenario this would lead to huge `orm.xml` as we have couple of huge queries.

I would like to achieve that each query would be stored in separate file, e.g. query for `UserRepository` `findByLastname` would be stored in `META-INF/User/findByLastname.jpql` or `META-INF/User/findByLastname.sql` if it is native query.

**Is it possible to achieve such query-per-file extraction in Spring Data JPA?**

PS: I am aware that query can be stored directly in `Repository` using `@Query` annotation but our maintenance team wants to have them extracted.

Thank you :-)

Comment: Your maintenance teams are insane.

Comment: "orm.xml" is absolutely nothing to do with Spring. It is JPA API. Not Spring Data JPA API either.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for your feedback. I talked to maintenance team and persuaded them not to require query extraction for every query. Query annotation is what I prefer as everything is in one place, which makes repositories easier to understand and refactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case you could use multiple orm.xml files with different name/locations:

```
<persistence-unit name="app-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    ...
    <mapping-file>mapping/orm-user.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>mapping/orm-settings.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>mapping/orm-data.xml</mapping-file>
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```